# How do I have a subscription email format a hyperlink in the comment field?

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

email delivery in ssrs 2005 won't format a hyperlink I enter in unless it generates it.  How do I get a hyperlink in the email text (the comment field in ssrs) instead of it being written out as plain text?

Answer (score 0):

Email Delivery in SSRS 2005 would have the Hyperlink if we "Include Link" which will automatically provides us the HyperLink. Correct me if I wrongly understood your question.